# VueJS applications not proxied correctly by nginx

Tags: vue.js, nginx, proxy

I am trying to set up an `nginx` proxy server on my local machine and forward two separate endpoints to two `VueJS` applications which are running on my local machine.

This `nginx` proxy server listens on port 5000 and watches `/app-1` and `/app-2` which proxies to `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8081` respectively, ie:

- `localhost:5000/app-1` will be forwarded to `localhost:8080` and
- `localhost:5000/app-2` will be forwarded to `localhost:8081`

This is what I have in the `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {

    listen       5000;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /app-1/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }

    location /app-2/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
```

I am getting an error with the above code:

[image]

It seems like the entry file to the `VueJs` application cannot be found. Is there some sort of relative path that needs to be added in `location`?

I managed to make it work with one app with the following in the `nginx.conf` file:

```
server {

    listen       5000;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
```

The above successfully proxies to `localhost:8080` and my `Vue` application runs successfully in the browser as shown.

[image]

When I tried and replace `location /` to `location/app-1/`, I ended up with the same `404 (Not Found)` error again.

How do I go about getting this fixed?

The objective of trying to achieve the above is to simulate both applications to be running on the same domain name on my local machine so both applications can access the same `localStorage`. The `localStorage` contains a `JWT` that will be used to make API calls. If a user is already authenticated in `app-1`, he/she should not need to be authenticated in `app-2` again.

In production, both applications will be deployed on the same domain name and thus will have access to the same `localStorage`. I am hoping to replicate the same production environment on my own local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an error in image it seems the page are be able to load then it try to load `app.js` from `http://localhost:5000/js/app.js` which is weird since your serve the Vue.js application under `/app-1/` and `/app-2/`.

So I think the problem is how your serve/build Vue.js application Not nginx proxy problem.

If you are using `Vue CLI`,

> By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain

You need to set [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) in `vue.config.js` to `/app-1/` and `/app-2/`.

I hope this help.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction! you are right. after setting the `publicPath` in `vue.config.js`, the resources can be found and the page loads.